# Location Service doesn't provide all data in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, reverse-geocoding

It shows me `(null) (null),Ahmedabad Gujarat (null) (null)`  when following code executes.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    _CurrentLocation = newLocation.coordinate;

    CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
    {
        for (CLPlacemark * placemark in placemarks)
        {
            NSString *addressTxt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@,%@ %@ %@ %@",
                                    [placemark subThoroughfare],[placemark thoroughfare],
                                    [placemark locality], [placemark administrativeArea], [placemark subLocality],[placemark subAdministrativeArea]];
            NSLog(@" >> %@",addressTxt);
            self.strLocation = [placemark locality];
        }
    }];
}
```

How to get other values ? Is location service will not provide these data in my area ? 
And if not then any alternative to get this data ?

Comment: take a look on it...it may helps u...http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk_clgeocoder--mobile-11011

Comment: And there is another alternative..that is google geocoding.. api.https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1